# Wordpress posts page for customer filtering and sorting along with category filter

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, sort

I've been struggling to implement WordPress posts (events) list page with the following functionality - Category filtering - Past event or Future event or Current event - Sort by event start date or event end date.

URL I am trying to implement is `http://mydomail.com/cateogry/technical/event_type/past/sort/current`

If you could help in following, it will be a great help.

How can I get all three parameters and pass to `WP_Query`?

Is it the best way to implement the URL as above? Or with query parameters?